# Performing UTM Lat Long Conversion?

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, latitude-longitude, utm

I have an inherently flawed system where we are using old data points (point surveys) set in lat longs and another set (transect surveys for another sp.) whose data was recorded in UTMs.

Is there a quick conversion or easy work around? I mean my GPS obviously uses both but is there like conversion?

Our map provided is in lat long minute decimals so it's just bound to be a headache as we find our multiple sites unless there's an easy converter/conversion I'm missing!

Comment: Do you simply need to find the points or locate them on a map?  If so, a better map might be simplest fix.  If you are doing calculations based on them, and/or have a huge number, software assistance may be needed.

Answer (score 2):

There are myriad converters online.  Here's the [first hit](http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx) in a [google search for "utm to lat long"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=utm%20to%20lat%20long).  It has a batch converter.  Depending on how your points are stored (spreadsheets? shapefiles?) and what software you've got available to you (ArcMap? QGIS? MapWindow?), there may be easier/better ways.